# What is preferred way to add discount tags over some product image using css?

Tags: html, css

What is preferred way to add discount tags over some product image using css?

My current implementation is this http://jsfiddle.net/ANtfG/7/

Html

```
<ul>   
    <li class="save_money">
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/food" />
        <span class="twenty-percent"  /></span>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.save_money{position:relative;float:left;margin:15px;background:yellow;display:inline}
.save_money img{position:absolute;}
.twenty-percent{background:url(http://canadianneighborpharmacy.net/images/cnp/discount_20.png);position:absolute; left:170px; top:-2px; width:45px; height:45px}
```

**I want to improve these two restriction in my current implementation or tell me the better way to achieve this**

1. How to align discount tag to `right`, not using `left:170px`? `right:0`
   doesn't work. and width of product images can be changed sometime
   then `left:170px` will not be flexible to width.
2. I'm using a Blank `span` element in mark-up I would like to know if
   there is another way to do it. Why I used `span` over `<img>` because I
   have different tags for 20%, 30%, 40% discount. SO i thought instead
   using `<img>` it would begood to add a span with classes like
   `.twenty-percent`, `.thirty-percent`, `.forty-prcent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to align discount tag to right, not using left:170px? right:0
>   doesn't work. and width of product images can be changed sometime then
>   left:170px will not be flexible to width.

Use `right: -15px`. That way, when you adjust the width, the "discount tag" will still be positioned correctly. `position: absolute` on the `img` must be removed, because with it the `li` has no width or height. I added `display: block` to remove the `~4px` of yellow space underneath the `img` caused by the `img` being `display: inline`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ANtfG/9/

> I'm using a Blank span element in mark-up I would like to know if
>   there is another way to do it. Why I used span over  because I
>   have different tags for 20%, 30%, 40% discount. SO i thought instead
>   using  it would begood to add a span with classes like
>   .twenty-percent, .thirty-percent, .forty-prcent

That's fine. The only other option would to omit the `span` and use `:before` - but of course, that won't work in older browsers such as IE7 (and it won't quite work in IE8 due to an IE8 bug).

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ANtfG/11/

---

You should fix this:

```
<span class="twenty-percent"  /></span>
```

to this:

```
<span class="twenty-percent"></span>
```

Comment: I tried `right:-15px` but it's not working as i want. see here http://jsfiddle.net/ANtfG/8/

Comment: Can we improve anything with `z-index`?

Comment: OK Thanks. you changed `position:absolute;` to `display:block`

Comment: I did. The other answers explain why.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue why `right: 0px;` (or maybe even `right: -20px;`) wouldn't work, is because you gave the img an absolute position.

Because of this, the surrounding li element doesn't get the same width as your image; and thus the -20% span gets positioned "wrongly" (maybe different is a better word).
By simply removing the `position:absolute` from the img, and replacing `left: 170px;` with `right: -20px;` you get about the same result, but which will resize along to the right with the image size :).

Comment: i also give that answer :( but +1

Answer (score 2):

@jitendra; ycheck this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/ANtfG/10/  `right:-15px` is works but your `li` is not taken the `width & height` of your `img` tag because it's `absolute position` .So, remove `position:absolute` from your `img` tag

Comment: Thanks. Positioning is also useful to keep one element another. Then in which condition z-index is required with positioning?

Comment: you can test your self write text in p tag with absolute position and define position like top:0; right:0; you get your answer in which condition z-index is required with positioning